# Error trying gem push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I made an update to one of my gems and now i have to release this new version, but when i try the gem push i receive the follow error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known   (http://gems.datamapper.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it would be difficult to write a question here if it would be down. Could you post the commands you typed, too?

Comment: No man, my network is working, and i'm trying this from yesterday until now, first i was think that the link in question is down, but a day after it still down, to be more clear i can't install gems, when i try to install a gem a get the same problem, thanks!

Comment: I typed 
$ gem build itau_shopline.gemspec
$ gem push itau_shopline-0.0.1.gem

Comment: This was a temporary outage I guess, because now i can push my gems, thanks everyone to help.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when your internet connection goes down.  I just got the error, went to google it, and realized my internet was down.  As soon as the internet was back up, I tried pushing the gem again, and the error went away.